# What would be the best way for me to insert data to table on form submit?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two tables `wallet` *(table 1)* and `api` *(table 2)*.

Right now I have made the part where I insert the submitted data to my `wallet` table. This is the code for this specifically:

```
<?php
   include 'db.php'; 

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

      $coin = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['coin']);
      $user_coins = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['coins_quantity']);

      $sql = "INSERT INTO wallet (coin, user_coins) VALUES ('$coin', '$user_coins')";
      if ($conn->query($sql)){
          echo "Added successfully.";
      } else{
          echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
      }

   }

?>
```

Where this is my form the code above:

```
<form method="post">
   <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Coin</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <select class="form-control" name="coin">
             <?php

             $sql = "SELECT name, symbol FROM api";
             $result = $conn->query($sql);

             while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                 unset($symbol, $name);
                 $symbol = $row['symbol'];
                 $name = $row['name'];
                 echo '<option value="'.$symbol.'">'.$name.'</option>';
              }
             ?>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Coins</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <input type="number" class="form-control" name="coins_quantity" placeholder="5">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row justify-content-center text-center">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

In my table `wallet` *(table 1)* I have created columns which are `coin`, `user_coins` and `coin_price`.

While in table `api` *(table 2)* I have `name`, `price`, `symbol` and more.

I want to insert data to `coin_price` in `wallet` from the `price` column in the `api` table, and I want the `price` from the selected `'<option value="'.$symbol.'">'.$name.'</option>';`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am a newborn PHP newbie, thank you for sharing the links. I will improve this code =)

Comment: Can we just modify your table because I think the coin and coin_price from your wallet table must be on the api table, and you just need to put the coin_id on the wallet table.

Comment: @TentenPonce I understand. I am looking for a solution for this, so if edition of the code comes with it, so be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way. You can:

1.) Put the `coin id` on the value of the select then,
2.) On your post method, find (`where clause`) the `coin id` and get the necessary data you want to insert them to another table.

Comment: I'll try this, thank you. By `coin id` are you referring to the id in `api` or `wallet`, I presume `api`.

Comment: Yes, im referring on the api table pardon.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most secure way to upload data to a table. You should use prepared statements to insert data using PHP.

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dml